# Convert PDF to JPG automatically on upload in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, imagemagick

I was wondering if anyone knows how to automatically convert PDF's to JPGs in Drupal when a user uploads, i'm able to create a script to do the actual conversion but my dilemma is being able to catch the file on upload and the process it. (or if there is a script/module that already does it it would be even better!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can do this with [ImageMagick raw action](http://drupal.org/project/im_raw) and [ImageCache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache).

Comment: I've spotted that too, but do you have any idea on implementation or links to it? i have tried to google but no luck :/

Comment: ImageCache is quite well documented: http://drupal.org/node/163561 . "ImageMagick raw action" gives you another action where you can enter an ImageMagick command line for converting pdf to jpg. which i think you have. doesn't sound too complicated. i won't test it for you, though :)

Answer (score 0):

The [CDN modules'](http://drupal.org/project/cdn) accompanying [file conveyor daemon](http://fileconveyor.org/) would probably do what you want (although this isn't technically Drupal)